# Is there a way to implement a web single sign on with BrightSpace platform?

Tags: authentication, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, desire2learn

I have a website were we are using Auth0 as Identity provider, now we are going to offer courses for our users, we want to integrate our site with the BrightSpace (desire2learn) LMS platform. The idea is to create the enrollment use case using their API in our site (create the user account), after that we want the user to have access to the LMS, avoiding the user to login again when passes from our site to the d2l platform site.

How should be the authentication flow to implement something like SSO in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, D2L Brightspace does support seamless login via an external redirect to your identify provider; however, the institution using Brightspace will need to work with their assigned D2L Implementation team in order to have SAML configured properly.

Comment: Do you have an example or source docs about this ? I didn't found anything related SAML implementation on Brightspace forum and docs. Thanks you